# how to design a database's table to store mysql spatial data in a parent child relation?

Tags: mysql, database-design, spatial

I want to store locations and polygon data in a parent-child relationship. I am using spatial data in MySQL and Google maps for polygon.

Examples:

```
1. World
1.1 US
1.2 China
1.3 Japan
1.4 South Africa
1.4.1 Pretoria
1.4.2 Cape Town
1.5 India
1.5.1 New Delhi
1.5.2 Chennai
```

etc.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geom` (

  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `g` geometry DEFAULT NULL,

  `location` varchar(100) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;


select * 
from geom 
where st_contains(g,(select g from geom where id =3))and id!=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your location table should have a self-reference. Use the Polygon[1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-datatypes.html) type for your geography.

eg:

```
LocationId (Primary key, not null)
LocationSequence (int, not null)
LocationName (string, not null)
parentLocationId (int, can be null)
Geographical data (POLYGON , not null)
```

So, your table might have:

```
1001, 1, World, null, ?
1002, 1, US, 1001, ?
1003, 2, China, 1001, ?
1004, 3, Japan, 1001, ?
1005, 4, South Africa, 1001, ?
1006, 1, Pretoria, 1005, ?
1007, 2, Cape Town, 1005, ?
1008, 5, India, 1001, ?
1009, 1, New Delhi, 1008, ?
1010, 2, Chennai, 1008, ?
```

Comment: Thank you dear dylanT,but what is 'LocationSequence'?

Comment: The idea is to build the 1.5.2 out of the sequence. You see that Chennai has a 2, it's parent (India) has a 5, and the World has a 1, so the ref number for Chennai would be 1.5.2

Comment: ok  dylanT. But my need is mysql Spatial function query. Now I edit question

Comment: Hmm. I don't have rep to post comment on question  yet. So, to clarify, you want a query that will give you all the polygons that contain a given polygon? So if you have the Chennai polygon, you would expect the query to give you "India" and "World"? And these polygons are derived from Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

To populate the following table from your geom table

```
CREATE TABLE location (
    parentLocationID INT, 
    LocationId INT NOT NULL, 
    LocationName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    Location GEOMETRY NOT NULL
);
```

The following inserts should work. Edit:  I have added a Buffer to work around a bug with ST_CONTAINS [Bug Link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69487)

```
-- Insert Top Level Locations
-- This is all geometries that are not contained by another geometry
INSERT INTO location (LocationId, LocationName, Location)
SELECT pp.id, pp.location, pp.g
FROM geom AS pp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM geom AS pt
    WHERE ST_CONTAINS(Buffer(pt.g,1), pp.g) = 1 AND -- Choose appropriate buffer value
        pt.id != pp.id
    );

-- Insert children
-- The join will return all ancestor geometries for the pc geom
-- The not exists statement removes all but the immediate ancestors for the pc geom
-- This is likely to run for quite some time
INSERT INTO location (parentLocationID, LocationId, LocationName, Location)
SELECT 
     pp.id , pc.id id, pc.location, pc.g
FROM geom AS pp
    INNER JOIN geom AS pc ON ST_CONTAINS(Buffer(pp.g,1),pc.g) = 1 AND -- Choose appropriate buffer value
        pp.id != pc.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM geom AS pt
    WHERE ST_CONTAINS(Buffer(pt.g,1),pc.g) = 1 AND -- Choose appropriate buffer value
        ST_CONTAINS(Buffer(pp.g,1),pt.g) = 1 AND -- Choose appropriate buffer value
        pt.id != pc.id AND 
        pt.id != pp.id
    );
```

I have tested this on SQL Server to 4 levels with the following dummy polygons, but beware if you have multiple equal geometries in your table. It will probably create a circular relationship.

```
INSERT INTO geom (g, location)
VALUES
(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 1000 0, 1000 1000, 0 1000, 0 0))'),'Level 1 Root')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((750 750, 950 750, 950 950, 750 950, 750 750))'),'Level 2 NE')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((50 750, 250 750, 250 950, 50 950, 50 750))'),'Level 2 NW')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((400 400, 600 400, 600 600, 400 600, 400 400))'),'Level 2 Center')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((50 50, 250 50, 250 250, 50 250, 50 50))'),'Level 2 SW')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((750 50, 950 50, 950 250, 750 250, 750 50))'),'Level 2 SE')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((100 100, 250 100, 250 250, 100 250, 100 100))'),'Level 3 SW1')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((50 50, 100 50, 100 100, 50 100, 50 50))'),'Level 3 SW2')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((750 50, 850 50, 850 100, 750 100, 750 50))'),'Level 3 SE1')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((900 100, 950 100, 950 150, 900 150, 900 100))'),'Level 3 SE2')
,(GeomFromText('POLYGON ((150 150, 200 150, 200 200, 150 200, 150 150))'),'Level 4 SW1');
```

My apologies if the syntax for mySQL isn't correct.

Comment: Thank you MickyT. Can you give the tested data too?

Comment: Sure, I have added it to the answer.  It is purely dummy data for testing.

Comment: I have just tested this in SQLfiddle and it doesn't work in mySQL.  [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cca5/2/0).  However in SQL Server it does [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0066f/2)